# View camera vs. Perspective camera (scheimpflug optics)

Tags: python, modeling, cycles-render-engine, camera

I've been searching extensively through this and other forums without success about the topic.
I am interested in using a new camera model consisting of a normal perspective model, but where the image plane is tilted with respect to the lens plane (scheimpflug principle).
I can't find how to modify a normal Cycles camera in order to include such "simple" modification.

Cheers

Pep

Answer (score 1):

You can skew the relation between the lens and the focal plane using the [SHIFT](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/camera/lens.html#shift) values for the lens. That will give you control of the perspective the same way you'd control a tilt/shift lens on a studio camera. There is no way AFIK to rotate the camera plane from the lens plane though.

[image]

[image]

This example show the same scene, with the same lens, WITH THE CAMERA ON THE SAME PLACE, and how shifting affects the perspective (I was trying to keep the object on the left in the frame to magnify the effect):

([Animated version here](https://i.imgur.com/3esWveu.gif))

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Blend file here:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that'll help. Very much appreciated